# No output on Sublime Text (compiler g++ version 6.3.0)

Tags: c++

I have not got RE on online programming website so i assume it should work on sublime text as well

Link to question : https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_k

why does my code does not give answer on sublime text when input of k is 10^5
The code still runs on online websites I am finding a reason why?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int dp[100002];
int solve(vector<int>&v,int k){
    if(k==0)return dp[0]=0;  //0 represents loosing,1 represent winning
    if(dp[k]!=-1){
        return dp[k];
    }
    

   //for any possible operation is there a loosing state if yes then he wins the game
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){ 
        
        if(k>=v[i] && solve(v,k-v[i])==0){
            return dp[k]=1;
        }
    }
    return dp[k]=0;
    
}


int main(){
    memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
    
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    vector<int>v(n);
    for(int &x : v){
        cin>>x;
    }
    solve(v,k);
    if(dp[k]==1){
        cout<<"First";
    }
    else cout<<"Second";



    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read how to provide a [mre].

Comment: ***why does my code does not give answer on sublime text when input of k is 10^5*** So it works for other inputs? Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Is that actually a code golfing contest or do you only use code-golfing patterns because you are unaware of the reasons for and against using them in different situations? If the latter, you are setting yourself up for some difficult unlearning and relearning later in your  programming life.

Comment: it gives output for input till 1e4 @kiner_shah

Comment: g++ 6.3.0 @kiner_shah

Comment: What does the output looks like when you give 10^5 as input for k? Can you update the post with the output? Please copy and paste the output, not images.

Comment: Actually it does not give any output as stated in title for values above 1e4 , it usually happens in my IDE if there is any RE ,but as it works on online compilers I was just wondered why does not show any output

Comment: @Vivek, you mentioned runtime error (RE). One possibility I noticed is when `k-v[i]` is negative, `if(dp[k]!=-1)` here it can crash while accessing `dp[k]` when `solve` is called recursively.

Comment: i have given a check for that k>=v[i] when i call solve() recursively

Comment: As my code got AC at Atcoder there is definitely no RE , I was just wondering why i did not got any output on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **Windows**: I suspect that you are not seeing output because the program is terminating before the console window even gets mapped the first time.

The fix is to get the user to press Enter before terminating your program.

```
int main()
{
  ...

  std::cout << "Press Enter to quit.";
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
}
```

(The line is repeated because your program does not clear the newline from prior inputs, so it must be cleared, then entered again to satisfy the prompt.)

If you are using **Linux**, make sure you start Sublime in a terminal window. If you start it from the menu it will not be attached to any output terminal.